# How does this PNP transistor circuit work?

Tags: transistors, led, bjt, pnp

How does this circuit work step by step and how do I get the LEDs to flash alternatively? (PNP transistors) (at what voltages do the LEDs turn on?)

[image: schematic]

Comment: What have you already tried? Where did you get stuck trying to figure this out?

Comment: Hi, I just need to know how it works.

Comment: When R5 is pulled to something below ground (probably -7 or -9V), then Q1 will turn on, causing LED1 to light.  That will drive Q2's base to GND, turning it and LED2 off.  Release R5 and Q1/LED1 turn off, and Q2/LED2 will turn on as it's base is now biased by LED1 and R4.  LED1 may glow very faintly at this time.     That's enough of a reply for you to get some understanding, but it's not gonna be enough to satisfy your professor  ;)     Think it through, simulate or build it if you have to.

Comment: Marking of positive and ground in the circuit seems to be wrong.

Comment: Just for the record. That's an awful way to draw that schematic. It goes against common best practices for drawing good schematics. Positive rails should be drawn at the top, negative ones at the bottom and consequently the PNPs should be drawn "upside down", i.e. with emitters at the top and collectors at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Look carefully at the battery symbol. The (+) side is tied to ground, and the (-) side is supplying the LEDs and the rest of the circuit. So it’s being powered by -7 to -9V. If you flip the drawing over it will make more sense.

With a battery symbol, the ‘short’ side is ‘cathode’ (-) and ‘long’ side ‘anode’ (+). That’s the only clue to the power supply polarity. My opinion, that’s a crappy drawing and a mean trick, but perhaps that’s the point of the exercise. Anyway…

Other than that, there’s nothing mysterious about this circuit. It’s a pair of PNP common-emitter amplifiers set up to drive LEDs. Q1 needs a base drive of at least -0.7V (the intention is probably that R5 be connected to battery (-) to turn Q1 on) and Q2 will invert that. Q1 on, Q2 off; Q1 off, Q2 on. This action will make the LEDs light alternately.

One issue: the first LED won’t turn off totally when Q1 is off, as it will be sinking base current to the second PNP, so it will glow faintly. Yes, even with just a few tens of micro amps.

Want to understand it more fully? Try a sim. May I suggest [Falstad](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html), an online Javascript-based simulator that visualizes voltage and current.

Answer (score 1):

This circuit is just two PNP transistors that are set to operate as either on or off. On being like a closed switch and off being open circuit between the collector and emitter terminals. Here though one transistor is connected directly to collector of first transistor so it will actually invert the operation of the first transistor. When the unconnected end of the 100k resistor is connected to negative terminal of 7 (or 9V) battery, current will flow through the 100k to establish -0.7 across base emitter junction and this turn on Q1. When Q1 is on, it’s collector emitter junction has a voltage of about -0.2V and allows current to flow through LED1. Since Vce1 is only -0.2V, this isn’t sufficient to turn Q2 on and thus LED2 is off.

When the 100k resistor is connected to ground, vbe1 is less than -0.7V and no base current flows, thus Q1 is off, therefore LED1 is off. However since Q1 is off, it’s collector emitter junction appears open circuit and voltage across LED1 and R4 are zero since no current flows or just a very very small current flows really.  This open circuit voltage across Q1 collector emitter junction is about -7V which can allow base current in Q1 to flow and turn on Q2 this turning on LED2.

To verify this, simulate the circuit in a spice circuit simulator.  Or better yet build this circuit on breadboard.